# Disable WebRTC detection in Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking to disable or at least partially disable WebRTC on selenium chromedriver,

The idea is to block potentially prevent all webRTC IP leak issues. I am testing this code from [How do I disable WebRTC in Chrome Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599265/how-do-i-disable-webrtc-in-chrome-driver)

```
# This code partially disables WebRTC
preferences = {
    "webrtc.ip_handling_policy" : "disable_non_proxied_udp",
    "webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled": False,
    "webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled" : False
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
```

I want to know if other potential solutions to this issue exist for Selenium ChromeDriver